# Creating a currency mask in vuetify 2 and v-mask

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mask, vuetify2

I am currently using the cdn version of v-mask for my vuetify 2 project. I have been asked to add a currency mask since here in the United States we tend to use thousandth digit comma separation. I am struggling to get it to work though as my range of numbers can be anywhere from the tens of thousands to the hundred billions. I figured I could just use v-mask with the mask amount to be a catch all but it seems to draw an error. Here is my implementation:

```
  <v-text-field
    v-model="totalDollarAmount"
    v-mask="'###,###,###,###,###.##'"
    label="(4) Total Dollar Amount"
    type="number"
    prefix="$"
    outlined
    required
    :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'Total Dollar Amount is required']"
    :error-messages="totalDollarAmountWarning"
  ></v-text-field>
```

The error it generates is as follows:

```
v-mask.min.js:1 The specified value "758,850,000," cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
```

The issue is the value may not occupy all the ### and therefore is drawing the error. This might need to be dynamic by dividing by 1000 or using modulus somehow but this seems overlycomplicated.

Comment: Thank you for that example. That is exactly what I need however I was curious the implementation of this addon. I am using options api but it does not like this notation in methods : currencyMask: textMaskAddons.createNumberMask().

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; >>> Static mask could have been replaced with dynamic mask function, but in Vuetify's case it does not work. A viable solution might be to introduce a wrapper around `v-text-field` inspired by [vuetify-mask](https://github.com/juareznasato/vuetify-mask) project.

I have originally suggested to drop `type="number"` and it would work with simple `<input />` [[1]](https://jsfiddle.net/1st4ewq7/). Dynamic mask has proven to work for manual inputs, but fail to load value from the API or any other async function.

I have played a bit with `v-text-field-money` and the only issue with it's current implementation is that it seems to expect a string with fraction digits. As a workaround we could use `Intl` to format the value used by the component.

```js
totalDollarAmount = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  useGrouping: false
}).format(valueFromAPI);
```

Comment: Yogi's response is now working for me after removing type as you said. However, my api returns the following value for the v-model : "DOLLAR_AMOUNT": 1.663800000000000e+007 . For some reason this value does not seem to get autofilled into the v-model like it use to. Now its blank. However, if i typed into the v-text-field the v-mask does in fact work. Do I need to convert my value to something first to make this work?

Comment: Also, your codebase is very nicely designed. If I cannot get this v-mask extension working I may just implement this.

Comment: @IrishRedneck I can reproduce it. It seems like dynamic mask does not play well with `v-text-field`. My previous example with simple `<input>` did not have this issue. It is actually so bizarre, when I set `@input` with async handler and artificially delay it, then I can see the input bounces between initial value and the one set by the server response handler. You might want to take a look at [vuetify-mask](https://github.com/juareznasato/vuetify-mask) instead - either to reuse `v-text-field-money` component or inspire yourself with it's implementation.

Comment: vuetify-mask looks promising. Do they offer a cdn to use for projects like mine that do not allow webpack? I could not find one but I am also really bad at knowing which links are actualy a full packaged cdn.